# Monotone and bounded or just bounded

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

I have to know if is it necessary that a sequence to be bounded and monotone to have a limit or it can be just bounded? For example, $A_{n+1}=1/(1+A_n)$, it is bounded but not monotone. However it has a limit! I'm a little bit confused, can someone give me a hint?

Comment: Convergent sequences need not be monotone.

Comment: how about $a_n = \sin(n)$  or  $a_n =  \dfrac{(-1)^n}{ n}$ etc...?

Comment: that was for OP David :)

Answer (score 1):

There is a sufficient condition for convergence, wich you seem to relate to:

> If a sequence $(a_n)_n$ is monotone and bounded, it converges.

However, the converse is not true (convergent $\not\Rightarrow$ monotone). Also both, boundedness and monotonicity are necessary for the proposition, bounded $\not\Rightarrow$ convergent (take $a_n = (-1)^n$ for example) and monotone $\not\Rightarrow$ convergent (take $a_n = n$ for example).

For short, monotone + bounded $\Rightarrow$ convergent $\Rightarrow$ bounded

Answer (score 0):

All convergent sequences are bounded.

All bounded sequences which are also monotone converge.

However, here are some examples showing that the converses of these statements need not be true:

1) Let $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be defined by $x_n = (-1)^n$. Then this sequence is bounded (between $-1$ and $1$), but does not converge.

2) Let $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be defined by $x_n = \sum\limits_{k=0}^n \frac{(-1)^k}{k!}$, then this sequence converges to $e^{-1}$, but is not monotone.

3) Let $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be the sequence $x_n = n$, then this sequence is monotone, but is not bounded and does not converge in $\Bbb{R}$ (it clearly diverges to $+\infty$).